# The objects in the scene looks good but in the game view looks too pixelated Unity 2019.4

Tags: unity-game-engine

I read something about this and i have to disable the «Low Resolution Aspect Ratios» but in i can't disable it beacuse unity doesn't let me.

[image: My unity scene and game view]

[image: Unity doesn't let me]

Comment: Well first of all it is further away ... Does it still look like this when you are closer?

Comment: Yes, it still looks like this when i'm closer

Answer (score 0):

My solution was using images with exactly the same resolution that i want in unity.
1 unit in unity is one pixel.